# Search specific text from file and output the line (Shell script)

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Suppose I have a variable $str1

```
str1="20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|"
```

What I want to do is search that part in the file. The file contains, for example:

```
20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|Perez|9173046751.000000|Mar 31|
20140121-21:50:28|Nikko|Real|9065887272.000000|Mar 21|
20140121-22:22:53|Czarina|Revilla|9999999999.000000|Jan 21|
```

The output should be:

20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|Perez|9173046751.000000|Mar 31|

Update: Finally know what the heck is the problem tried to `echo $str1` and it outputs `20140121|Adrian Perez|` meaning it really ISN'T in the file. Haaa! I'm such a mess! -_-

Comment: you can simply use grep. e.g. `grep $str filename.txt`

Comment: @mcantsin I tried that, it didn't work

Comment: and what's the error? - No output?

Comment: @mcantsin yup no output!

Comment: I tested your example and it works perfectly for me. - Sure there is no typo?

Comment: @mcantsin just tried it again without quotes and here's the error: `grep: Perez|: No such file or directory`

Comment: don't forget the parenthesis `"`

Comment: oh you mean quotation marks? @mcantsin yup i added those (previously) and there's no output

Comment: as Jobin mentioned. Check [quoting variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

Comment: @mcantsin yup thanks for your help! read my update above haha sorry, i guess i just need to rest. good night! (or good morning?)

Comment: Typo happenz. Good night

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this:

```
grep "$str" filename.txt
```

to prevent misinterpretation of special characters.

To know more, refer this:

- [Quoting variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)